# Paste and Execute Multiple Lines from Clipboard in Spyder Ipython Console

Tags: python, ipython, spyder

I would like to paste the following code into the ipython console in spyder (i.e directly from the clipboard to the console)

```
nsample = 100
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
```

[image]

I've pasted the 2 lines into the Ipython console in Spyder in the image above. How could I then execute the 2 lines shown in the console window from spyder? Everytime I press enter it just inserts a new line with a "...:" prompt.

Additionally, I see that Spyder doesn't let me use the %paste command. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: I had the same problem, I found that going to the end of the line and hit <enter> twice helped.

Answer (score 1):

You need to press SHIFT+Enter to tell the interpreter you have entered all the commands. The "..." means the interpreter expects you to enter more commands.